# insert string across multiple divs with Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, insert, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I'm trying to insert a comma in a price div. The prices are being pulled from the database.

So far I've got this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("portfolio_price").innerHTML;
    var len = x.length;
var y = x.substring(0, len-3) + "," + x.substring(len-3);
     document.getElementById("portfolio_price").innerHTML = y;
}
 myFunction()
```

Which is fine for changing one, but I need need it to change all the divs that display on the page.

All feedback welcome as always.

Comment: This would be a simple task with JQuery.  Do you have access to JQuery?

Comment: All DIV elements, as in all of them, not just ones with a certain class or other identifier, but every last DIV there is

Answer (score 0):

Add a class name to each element and use [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with the [CSS-selector for class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) to retrieve the list of all elements with that class. Then iterate over the elements using [NodeList.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) and passing it that function as a callback.

See this demonstrated in the example below. The commas will be added when the user clicks the button containing the text '*Add Commas*'.

```js
function addCommas() {
  //get a list of elements with class attribute containing 'portfolio_price'
  var priceContainers = document.querySelectorAll(".portfolio_price");

  //run the function on each element in the list
  priceContainers.forEach(function(priceContainer) {
    var x = priceContainer.innerHTML;
    var len = x.length;
    var y = x.substring(0, len - 3) + "," + x.substring(len - 3);
    priceContainer.innerHTML = y;
  });
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var button = document.getElementById('addCommas');
  button.addEventListener('click', addCommas);
});
```

```html
<div class="portfolio_price" id="price_1">10.20</div>
<div class="portfolio_price" id="price_2">10.20</div>
<button id="addCommas">Add Commas</button>
```

As  Luvn Jesus suggests, you could use `jQuery` or a similar library to take advantage of helper functions. For example,

```
var priceContainers = document.querySelectorAll(".portfolio_price");
```

can be simplified to

```
var priceContainers = $(".portfolio_price");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple elements with same ID. That's why it only returns one time. Change the ID to Class.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to get this jQuery working in jFiddle:

```
 function addCommas(nStr)
 {
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
    x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
       return x1 + x2;
 }

$(function(){
   $(".format").each(function(c, obj){
      $(obj).text(addCommas(parseFloat($(obj).text()).toFixed(2)));
   });
});
```

But I can't seem to get it going on the wordpress site I'm working on. I'm playing around with `jQuery.noConflict();`, but honestly I'm pretty confused.